# Nested view template not loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a tabbed interface that preserves state using AngularJS, UI Router and UI Router Extras and based on this [example](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html#/).

It works fine if I don't use a nested view with an abstract state (nested under 'tabs'), but when I do use the nested view the template doesn't load. I assume that I am declaring my view or state incorrectly:

```
      $stateProvider.state('tabs', { abstract: true,  url: '/tabs', template: '<ui-view ng-transclude/>', transclude: true });
      $stateProvider.state('tabs.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        views: { 'tab1@tabs': { template: '<div>this is tab 1 <input type="text" autocomplete="off"/></div>'}},
        deepStateRedirect: true, sticky: true
      });

<div ui-view="tabs">
  <div ui-view="tab1"></div><div ui-view="tab2"></div>
</div>
```

[Full example at JB Bin](http://jsbin.com/wacicipijuno/1/) ([source](http://jsbin.com/wacicipijuno/1/edit)).

Is it possible to declare my nested views like this? Or do I have to put the 'tabs' view into an external file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [updated working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MszTDP8xJi25WBc4FQxC?p=preview)

Firstly, I've removed the content of the `tabs` target

```
<div ui-view="tabs"></div>
```

and moved that into state def:

```
$stateProvider.state('tabs', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/tabs',
    //template: '<ui-view ng-transclude/>',
    views: {
      'tabs@': {
        template: '<div><div ui-view="tab1"></div><div ui-view="tab2"></div></div>'
      }
    },
    transclude: true
  });
```

Also, as we can see I've changed the original:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tabs', { 
        ...
        template: '<ui-view ng-transclude/>'
```

to the above mentioned `views : {}` definition, because we need to target named view **`'tabs@'`**. Check the:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) *(cite:)*

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of **`viewname@statename`**, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

Comment: That works thanks, but is it possible without removing the content of the `tabs` target?

Comment: I'd say: why should we do/try that? With the `ui-router` we are provided with a set of very powerful features, like multi-views and state-nesting. They do have their own architecture/design, which when followed - it brings fruits. Other words, changing/tweaking this really does not bring any new value. Just issues. So, I would suggest: do it the most standard way. Later you will enjoy it *(e.g. having still upgrade ready usage, once ui-router will have new version)*